# Oracle SQL: How to use more than 1000 items inside an IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an SQL statement where I would like to get data of 1200 `ep_codes` by making use of `IN` clause. When I include more than 1000 `ep_codes` inside IN clause, Oracle says I'm not allowed to do that. To overcome this, I tried to change the SQL code as follows:

```
SELECT period, ...
FROM   my_view
WHERE  period = '200912'
       ...
       AND ep_codes IN (...1000 ep_codes...)
       OR  ep_codes IN (...200 ep_codes...)
```

The code was executed succesfully but the results are strange (calculation results are fetched for all periods, not just for 200912, which is not what I want). Is it appropriate to do that using `OR` between `IN` clauses or should I execute two separate codes as one with 1000 and the other with 200 ep_codes?

---

Pascal Martin's solution worked perfectly. Thanks all who contributed with valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not sure that using so many values in a `IN()` is that good, actually -- especially for performances.

When you say "*the results are strange*", maybe this is because a problem with parenthesis ? What if you try this, instead of what you proposed :

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
      AND (
          ep_codes IN (...1000 ep_codes...)
          OR  ep_codes IN (...200 ep_codes...)
      )
```

Does it make the results less *strange* ?

Comment: I've updated the question to make things clear about the strange results. Now I'm trying the code as you proposed (with extra parentheses). As soon as the results are fetched, I'll tell you.

Comment: Thanks, it works OK now. Once again I see that how extra parentheses are crucial.

Comment: You're welcome :-) -- yes, parenthesis can be helpful ;-)

Answer (score 28):

The recommended way to handle this in Oracle is to create a Temporary Table, write the values into this, and then join to this. Using dynamically created `IN` clauses means the query optimizer does a 'hard parse' of every query.

```
create global temporary table LOOKUP
(
    ID NUMBER
) on commit delete rows;

-- Do a batch insert from your application to populate this table
insert into lookup(id) values (?)

-- join to it
select foo from bar where code in (select id from lookup)
```

Comment: We recently changed some code from using "in" to using a temporary lookup table. For some queries the performance increased dramatically from taking several minutes to within a second.

Comment: But is this a valid implementation for multiple parallel requests to server? As far as I understand there can be several open transactions on Oracle server, trying to create `LOOKUP` table

Comment: @Ilya: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240810/when-will-data-in-oracle-session-temporary-table-get-deleted. With "on commit delete rows", the data should only be visible within the scope of the transaction.

Comment: @retronym: Interesting answer, I've tried this within our project. But it took to much time for me. Potentially I did something wrong with data insert. Namely I have approximately 2500 values that should be inserted to temporary table. Could you please advise how this amount of values should be correctly inserted to oracle DB?

Answer (score 7):

Actually you can use collections/multisets here. You'll need a number table type to store them.

```
CREATE TYPE NUMBER_TABLE AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
...
SELECT *
FROM my_view
WHERE period MEMBER OF NUMBER_TABLE(1,2,3...10000)
```

Read more about multisets [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0520__Collections/MULTISETOperator.htm):

Comment: This is very elegant syntactically but the performance is disappointing.  Using this syntax to select a single primary key value the CBO chooses an INDEX FAST FULL SCAN.

Comment: Testing with a couple thousand ids and a moderate sized table (40K rows), it is still about 3x faster than joining on a temp table (due to the hash join). That's not counting the time to create and populate the temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it would be a better idea, both for performance and maintainability, to put the codes in a separate table.

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE ...
   AND ep_code in (select code from ep_code_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

could you insert the 1200 `ep_code` values into a temporary table and then `INNER JOIN` to that table to filter rows instead?

```
SELECT a.*
FROM mytable a
INNER JOIN tmp ON (tmp.ep_code = a.ep_code)
WHERE ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure about it. I'm using some views that IT has provided for me.