# SQL IN comma separated parameters vs inner query

Tags: sql, performance

I know that there is a limit of 1000 items in the SQL IN clause.
Currently, I am using a comma separated string of items in "`IN`" clause of a select query and I want to change it.

So, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722220/sql-in-clause-1000-item-limit), which states to use either `JOIN` or pass a query inside `IN` itself.

Which one should be preferred choice ?

EDIT (Another Question):

What is the difference in passing query in "`IN`" clause and passing comma separated parameters in "`IN`" clause ?

Comment: The database optimizer will execute both variants in the same way.  You can use the one that looks better. :)

Comment: Are you **actually** using a query with 1,000 comma-separated items in an `in` clause?  0_0  Srsly, put them in a table and join appropriately.

Comment: @JackManey: Not now but in future there are chances.

Comment: @HardikMishra - In that case, put them in a table and join appropriately (or use an `in` statement such as `column in (select column from table_with_tons_of_values_oh_god_dont_want_to_list_them_all)`).

Comment: @Andomar:Please paste your comment as answer. I found it helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database optimizer will execute both variants in the same way. You can use the one that looks better. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you put a query in the "In clause" the database need to calc this query first and than based on the result calc the "main query". 
if you put values in the "In clause"  the database dost need to calc additional query.

As concern to join against query in the in clause the database will optimise them to be the same.

Comment: So,you mean to say putting values is good rather than query ?

Comment: From clear performance point of view putting values is faster since its dosnt required to execute additional query, but performance is not the only perspective . if the differnce is 1 ms and 1 ms is negligible for you , so take the clearance approach.

Comment: Its true when you have fewer values but when values are more than 1k, then SQL itself has limitation on IN clause.So, This is not the solution what I was looking for.