# How many parameters can sql query contain when being executed in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

If I write a query like

```
select * from some_table where some_field in (1, 2, 3 ...)
```

then how long can this list be for query to be successfully executed?

Comment: Please note that if the list is longer than a dozen or so, there are probably better ways of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted from

Oracle® Database SQL Language Reference
11g Release 2 (11.2)
Part Number E26088-01

"You can specify up to 1000 expressions in expression_list."

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted to know

Answer (score 1):

Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722220/sql-in-clause-1000-item-limit) help?

Looks like it may be limited to 1000 items in the IN clause but you can get around that by sub querying. Be careful with a large number of items in the IN clause as it could affect performance.

Comment: Regarding Oracle 11 uses the same way for IN clause as well as EXISTS I'm pretty sure the performance will not be affected significantly.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted to know