# How to use an arraylist as a prepared statement parameter

Tags: java, arraylist, prepared-statement

I have looked and have been unable to find an answer to the following challenge I am having.  It
seems pretty straightforward but I have been unable to resolve it.

I have an `ArrayList` of record ids that are type `Long` -> `ArrayList<Long>`.  I would like to use
this list of record ids to select rows from another table.  So far so good.  Now onto the 
challenge...

a) I am using a prepared statement to select the data from a table using the `ArrayList` as input
   for this.

```
selectPS = dbConnection.prepareStatement("select columnA from tableA where id in ?");
```

Question on the above - how should the parameter be defined?  The above does not seem correct for
   an `ArrayList` type parameter.

b) I am also running into problems when setting the value of the parameter for the prepared
   statement.  There is no method for setting an `ArrayList` type value and I see no other viable
   options.

```
---> selectPS.set?????(1, arraylistParameter);
     ResultSet rs = selectPS.executeQuery();
```

Any help or direction you can set me in is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: **Can you try passing an array ?** , [PreparedStatement#setArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setArray(int,java.sql.Array)) ? You need to create an array first using [Connection#createArrayOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createArrayOf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object[])). There are certain ways listed [here](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/Journal200510.jsp#a2).

Comment: I would dynamically create a String with a `?` for each element in the array, the call the `setLong` method with each value, incrementing the index each time.

Comment: @Thomas Grady CBIP What is your database ? If it is Oracle,then won't support more than 1000 records in `IN` clause.You have to write INNER JOIN clause more info - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722220/sql-in-clause-1000-item-limit

Comment: @Prabhaker... We are using MySQL.  That said, it is not the sql that is the challenge but getting my prepared statement set-up correctly to make use of an array list.  Thanks for forwarding the information just the same.

Comment: Hi all.  I went with the suggestion to loop thru the arraylist and to set the Long parameter for each call and I have what I need.  Though there seems to be more overhead with this option, the number of rows read is a couple of thousand and it is to fix a production issue.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You may want to use `setArray` method as mentioned in the javadoc below:

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setArray(int, java.sql.Array)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setArray%28int,%20java.sql.Array%29)

Sample Code:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = 
                conn.prepareStatement("select * from employee where id in (?)");
Array array = conn.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", new Object[]{"1", "2","3"});
pstmt.setArray(1, array);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Getting back to you (and TNI) on the suggestion of using an array.  Unfortunately I cannot use that due to us having MySQL as our database.  MySQL does not support an sql array.  It is too bad because this would have addressed my need as well.  Thanks your your help.

Comment: I'm basically using this code, however I'm getting a `text = text[]` error. Would it be possible to show what the result query would be?
I expect something like this: `SELECT * FROM employee where id in ('{"1", "2","3"}')` as it does in my code.

Comment: For the comment above; haven't solved why I'm getting the error, but using `SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id = ANY (?)` does work (for me).

Comment: This will not work on Oracle Databases, because createArrayOf is not implemented

Comment: Not working in Informix either, also because createArrayOf is not implemented

Answer (score 26):

If you have **ArrayList** then convert into **Array[Object]**

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
PreparedStatement pstmt = 
            conn.prepareStatement("select * from employee where id in (?)");
Array array = conn.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", list.toArray());
pstmt.setArray(1, array);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Could someone confirm if this works? I got an error java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.createArrayOf

Comment: NO, it does not work because it returns an error: java .sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException

Comment: Be aware that this won't work on Oracle Databases, as @Jorge Machado mentioned above

Answer (score -11):

@JulienD
Best way is to break above process into two steps.

**Step 1 :** 
Lets say 'rawList' as your list that you want to add as parameters in prepared statement.

Create another list :

```
ArrayList<String> listWithQuotes = new ArrayList<String>();

for(String element : rawList){
    listWithQuotes.add("'"+element+"'");
}
```

**Step 2** : 
Make 'listWithQuotes' comma separated.

```
String finalString = StringUtils.join(listWithQuotes.iterator(),",");
```

'finalString' will be string parameters with each element as single quoted and comma separated.

Comment: This is a bad idea, because it will open you to SQL injection.

Answer (score -28):

why making life hard-

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from employee where id in ("+ StringUtils.join(arraylistParameter.iterator(),",") +)");
```

Comment: Because SQL Injection