# ORA-01722 invalid number for where condition with IN

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, hibernate, named-query

Here is my code:

`String sql = "UPDATE EmployeeEXT SET bonus = 1 WHERE empId IN (:empIds);
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.setParameterList("empIds",  employeeIds);
query.executeUpdate();`

**EmployeeEXT Table structure** is like

```
 EmployeeEXT_ID Number(19)
 BONUS          Number(5)
 EMPID          Number(19)
```

**EmployeeEXT.java Pojo**

```
Class EmployeeEXT {
 private long   employeeEXTId;
 private long   bonus;
 private Employee emp; //Many-TO-ONE Relation

  // setter and getter methods.
}
```

Hibernate parameterList setting long list for empIds parameter.
But oracle giving **ORA-01722 Invalid number**.

I guess the reason is hibernate replacing 'empIds` parameter with a cama separated long values, so oracle feeling it as string, but when I sending single value it's working.

The same peace of code working fine for MYSQL.

Somebody help me to work fine with hibernate query parameterList.

Comment: Removed tag [Java]. Not all MySQL code is Oracle compatible. You can use `to_number` as described [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_01722_invalid_number.htm).

Comment: `to_number` only work for single value but in my case it may contain multiple values

Comment: What's the datatype of this variable `employeeIds`?

Comment: `employeeIds` type is `ArrayList<Long>`

Comment: You can try converting to `ArrayList<Integer>` like this `employeeIds.stream().map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());` This is also to check the your `Long` values are indeed in `Integer` range.

Comment: I think this is the answer to  your question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842211/how-to-use-an-arraylist-as-a-prepared-statement-parameter).