# Select where id = array (Oracle JDBC)

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

I'm currently working with trying to compare an ID in Oracle(A VARCHAR2) with an array of IDs I have as input.

This is what I want to do:

```
Select user, city where id = :arrayOfIds
```

In Postgres with JDBC I would use:

```
Select user, city where id = any(:arrayOfIds)
```

Is there an equivalent function in Oracle, or a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
Select user, city where id in (:arrayOfIds)
```

and in you code, you need to trasform your array in string with ids:

```
arrayOfIds[0] --> 1
arrayOfIds[1] --> 3
arrayOfIds[2] --> 5
```

...
in

```
1, 3, 5, ...
```

and you can use:

```
Array array = conn.createArrayOf("arrayOfIds", new Object[]{"1", "2","3"});
pstmt.setArray(1, array);
```

[How to use an arraylist as a prepared statement parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842211/how-to-use-an-arraylist-as-a-prepared-statement-parameter)

Comment: The Oracle JDBC driver does not support `createArrayOf()`