# No results "In" clause in PreparedStatement with 2 objects

Tags: java, jdbc

I passed a lot of time to find the solution but I can't still.

I found some solution about how to pass "IN" elements into PreparedStatement, but if there is any other solution I'd be glad to see that, but, anyway I have

```
RowMapper<Map<BigInteger, Status>> mapper = new QueryDescriptionById.RowMapperDescription();

@Override
public Multimap<BigInteger, Status> findObject(BigInteger[] ids) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Object id : ids) {
        builder.append("?,");
    }
    String statement = SQL + builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1).toString() + ")";

    Multimap<BigInteger, Status> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    intoMap(multimap, getJdbcTemplate().query(statement, ps -> {
        int index = 1;
        for (BigInteger id : ids) {
            ps.setInt(index++, id.intValue());
        }
    }, mapper));
    return multimap;
 }

private void intoMap(Multimap<BigInteger, Status> multimap, List<Map<BigInteger, Status>> list) {
    list.forEach(map -> map.forEach((multimap::put)));
}

class RowMapperDescription implements RowMapper {
        @Override
        public Map<BigInteger, Status> mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Status status = new Status();
            Map<BigInteger, Status> map = new HashMap<>();
            BigInteger id = rs.getBigDecimal("ID").toBigInteger();
            BigInteger parentId = rs.getBigDecimal("PARENT_ID").toBigInteger();
            status.setId(id);
            status.setDescription(rs.getString("attempt_status_text"));
            map.put(parentId, status);
            return map;
        }
    }
```

But it works well while I pass in BigInteger[] only 1 element but when there are 2 or more it doesn't into my mapper.

Why ?

**P.S**

Instead RowMapper I've tried to use ResultSet like

```
return getJdbcTemplate().query(SQL, ids, resultSet -> {
            Multimap<BigInteger, Status> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
            int rowNum = 0;
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println("rownum = " + rowNum);
                mapper.mapRow(resultSet, rowNum++).forEach(multimap::put);
            }
            return multimap;
        })
```

But in the console wasn't any lines which mean that resultSet hasn't `next()`

**P.S.S**

My `SQL` is where hard so I put only a short version. It looks like

```
private String SQL = "select el1,el2 from mytable where el3 in(";
```

I've tried  instead `in(";` and `in :ID` and `in = :ID` and `in (:ID)` and `in (?)` and some other variants which I don't remember (-:

**EDITED**

Actually, I don't understand, why that works

```
public QueryDescriptionBySmsId(DataSource dataSource) {
    super(dataSource, SQL);
    logger.debug("Created QueryStatus");
    declareParameter(new SqlParameter("ID", Types.NUMERIC));
    compile();
    logger.debug("Created QueryStatus");
}

@Override
public Multimap<BigInteger, Status> query(Set<BigInteger> ids) {
       Map<String, Set> paramMap = Collections.singletonMap("ID", smsIds);
       List l = executeByNamedParam(paramMap); // it returns a lot of elements which I am looking for
}
```

But that doesn't work

```
 @Override
 public Multimap<BigInteger, SmsStatus> query(Set<BigInteger> sids) {

        Map<String, Set> paramMap = Collections.singletonMap("ID", ids);
        return getJdbcTemplate().query(SQL,  resultSet -> {
            int rowNum = 0;
            Multimap<BigInteger, SmsStatus> multimap = 
 ArrayListMultimap.create();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                mapper.mapRow(resultSet, rowNum++).forEach(multimap::put);
            }
            return multimap;
        },paramMap);
 }
```

It shows an error

> SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type

Comment: What does the resulting query look like? It seems as if the part in `SQL` already contains the opening parenthesis ...

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Some support passing in arrays.

Comment: @Thilo, Oracle, or what do you mean :-P

Comment: Then this could work: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45914325/14955. Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/17842297/14955

Comment: @Thilo, It good links, But I forgot to say I use Spring and I haven't `Connection` or `Statement`. I can reach on `getJdbsTemplate()` ...... I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8428360/9719337)

Comment: Maybe this then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1327222/14955

Comment: @Thilo, it was first that I've tried :-)  Now, I try your last post in my program, several minutes till compilation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195996/discussion-between-dred-and-thilo).

Comment: @Thilo
I make 
Object[] ids =
`Array array = connection.createArrayOf("NUMERIC", new Object[]{"18739395","23343912"}); `

And get SQLState =99999 
java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported function. 


Instead `NUMERIC` i've tried `number` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed my code like that and it works now, but I don't like that solution

```
public class QueryDescriptionById extends SqlQuery implements IQueryDescriptionById {

RowMapper<Map<BigInteger, Status>> mapper = new RowMapperDescription();

public QueryDescriptionById(DataSource dataSource) {
    super(dataSource, SQL);
}

public Multimap<BigInteger, SmsStatus> query(Set<BigInteger> ids) {

    Map<String, Set> paramMap = Collections.singletonMap("ID", ids);
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource());

    return template.query(SQL, paramMap, resultSet -> {
        int rowNum = 0;
        Multimap<BigInteger, Status> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            mapper.mapRow(resultSet, rowNum++).forEach(multimap::put);
        }
        return multimap;
    });
}
.........
.........
.........
}
```

Comment: What don't you like about it? You are directly setting your list of numbers into a single query parameter. Isn't that the ideal solution?

Comment: @Thilo, because my class extends `SqlQuery` and in other classes which were created before me it was realised with something like `declareParameter(new SqlParameter("ID", Types.NUMERIC)); compile();   Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();    params.put("ID", cnrId);  return executeByNamedParam(params);` Also, I mean, that I use my `SQL` statement twice, in constructor and in my `query(Set)` method. Its bad