# How to assign a value to the MySQL statement with the in keyword in Java？

Tags: java, mysql

The parameters to be passed are the int type and the quantity is uncertain.
How can I pass all the parameters at once in the case of uncertain parameters?

```
String SQL = "select * from table where enterprise_id in (?,?,?)";
int a,b,c = 1,2,3;//uncertain quantity
this.server.findBySql(SQL,a,b,c);
```

Is there a good way to avoid traversing parameters and splicing the query statements?

Comment: What do you mean by uncertain quantity?

Comment: I don't know how many int type parameters are passed in, that is, I don't know how many "?" behind in

Comment: Which technology you are using to connect `MySQL`? Like `JDBCTemplates`? I think any `preparedStatement` will allow you to add a parameter which is of type list, which is expected in the `IN` clause.

Comment: @VPK It's jdbcTemples

Comment: @VPK I tried, but it didn't succeed

Comment: Are you using `Spring`?

Comment: @VPK no,i just use int

Comment: Sorry, it's wan't `String`, I mean, are you using `Spring-framework`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to pass a list is to use 
`org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource.MapSqlParameterSource()` which can take any type of argument for a prepared statement.

So, in your case, you can modify your `SQL` like this to take list parameter:

```
String sql = "select * from table where enterprise_id in (:listOfInt)";.
```

Then add the list as parameter:

```
MapSqlParameterSource sqlParams = new MapSqlParameterSource();        
sqlParams.addValue("listOfInt", Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
```

Pass it to the `org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` instance to execute the query like this,

```
this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, sqlParams);
```

Which gives you a resultset, further this assumes that you have created an instance of `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` at the class level.

Answer (score 0):

I'am not a Java dev, but you shall pass an array parameter to an `IN` SQL statement:

```
String SQL = "select * from table where enterprise_id in (?)";
int[] array = {1, 2, 3};//uncertain quantity
this.server.findBySql(SQL, array);
```

please see [How to use an arraylist as a prepared statement parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842211/how-to-use-an-arraylist-as-a-prepared-statement-parameter) for the right way to do this.

Be carefull, if your array may be very large (I mean, very very large), you better have to insert it into a temporary table using a bulk insert and then to use a `JOIN` statement (but only if you may reach the MySQL `IN` limits).

Answer (score 0):

We can definitely pass array of type int to stored procs, but not sure about statements.

However we can get away with workaround like this.

Let's say int values are coming from int[] arrData.

```
StringBuffer arguments= new StringBuffer();

for(Integer value:arrData){
 if(arguments.toString().length!=0)
  arguments.append(",");
  arguments.append(""+value+"");
}
```

and then finally pass comma separated values as input like this.

```
String SQL = "select * from table where enterprise_id in (?)";
this.server.findBySql(SQL,arguments.toString());
```

Comment: `""+value+","`: The last element will also have `,`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat completely agree with you. You can share new version of refined solution.

Comment: In this way, it seems to be only looking for data that meets the first parameter

Comment: You don't have to use sarcasm for this right? If I had to post an answer I would have already written it. Chill bro. Me yahan tumse zhagde karne nahi aaya hu ;)