# oracle 11g sql compare larger number of values

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I am writing the java program in which I need to compare the large number of `List<String> ids` to see are these ids are exist in the database ? I know it can be done with big select query `select id from my_table where id in ('1','2''3''4''5'...)` which leads very big sql query.

is there any other way of doing this in Oracle 11g ?

Thanks

Comment: Use BETWEEN if you have distinct ids.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should be aware of Oracles `IN` clause limit ([SQL IN Clause 1000 item limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722220/sql-in-clause-1000-item-limit)). So you could avoid this if you split your large `in` into smaller ones like

```
select id from my_table where id in ('1','2','3') or id in ('4','5'...)
```

or run multiple requests in Oracle

```
select id from my_table where id in ('1','2','3');
select id from my_table where id in ('4','5'...);
```

or there are other possibilites (see linked question).