# Oracle IN Clause Loop Join to Work Around 1000 Limit

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400255/how-to-put-more-than-1000-values-into-an-oracle-in-clause) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722220/sql-in-clause-1000-item-limit) and couldn't find a workaround for my situation. My conditions are as follows:

1. I have 7000+ conditions (all unique values) for the IN clause
2. I only have read-only priveleges for the corporate DB. I'm hesitant to try the temporary table solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722220/sql-in-clause-1000-item-limit).

Is it possible to loop through a transaction to query all records that meet the 7000 IN conditions? My company uses Oracle.

Comment: The question you have linked has several alternative answers besides creating a temp table-- (or clause, union) you should use one of those

Comment: You will need to create a temporary table, there is no work around. You could ask for permissions to create a table.

Comment: Where do you store 7000+ values? Where are they coming from?

Comment: 7000 values need to (ideally) go in the IN clause but obviously can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit on an IN statement, you can deal with it in a number of ways. You will have to create a temporary table. This is a duplicate of: [SQL IN Clause 1000 item limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722220/sql-in-clause-1000-item-limit)

You can do a join on the data:

```
  SELECT  b.foo 
FROM    ( 
        SELECT  DISTINCT stuff 
        FROM    asdf ) a 
JOIN    bar b 
ON      b.stuff = a.stuff
```

You can do an EXISTS

```
 SELECT  a.id 
 FROM asdf
 WHERE
  a.id EXISTS (
     SELECT b.id from bnml b 
     where b.id = a.id
 )
```