# Disable limitation SQL IN Clause 1000 item limit

Tags: java, oracle, configuration

We have a framework that used In statement in several sections and also in core of it's code and developers did NOT know or forgot to keep in their mind this limitation,
Now by adding offices in out program this ERROR appear in logs.
I want to know that is possible to disable this limitation? or Increase it's value to for example 10000?
I know this limitation in for performance but our priority in this case is running our query without error.

EDIT:I CAN'T EDIT QUERIES RIGHT NOW.

Sincerely

Comment: Why don't you just load those 1000 values into a temporary table or CTE, and use that instead?

Comment: I don't know if it's configurable. Probably not. The developers will probably need to change their code, for example by following the advice in these answers:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722220/sql-in-clause-1000-item-limit

Comment: The codes are in framework and developed by another company.

Comment: @Klas Lindbäck  I read it ago, I can't change queries right now.

Comment: @Klas Lindbäck So if we have a program that it's source can't be change, we can't use it?

Comment: *"is possible to disable this limitation?"* Nope, this limitation is [hard baked into the SQL engine](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/expressions016.htm#SQLRF52099). I would guess it's related to the 1000 column limit for tables. So, this seems like a bug in the framework. Throw it back to the developers to fix. An `IN` clause with 1000 expressions is Teh Suck! anyway.

Comment: @mojtabadddd If you (or rather, the owners of the data) can remove entries so there are under 1000 items, then it can be used for now. The long term solution is to fix the bug/limitation in the framework code.

Comment: @APC Thanks you, I'm wonder why developers did not mention this limitation when developing system.

Comment: @Klas Lindbäck This is accessible offices of a user, so there is no way to reduce them.