# Delete multiple records from huge table

Tags: oracle, database-performance, delete-row

I would like to delete a few records (100 thousand records) from a table containing 10 million records in an Oracle database. When I tried to delete the records using the below query

```
DELETE from TEST where ID in (1,2,3,4,1000,,, etc)
```

It looks like there is limitation of 1000 values, hence the below error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-01795: maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000
```

Is there any query to delete more than 1000 records in a single statement without using PL/SQL?

I am thinking of something like the following - please suggest the correct query:

```
DELETE  from TEST where ID in (1,2,3,4,1000)
AND
DELETE  from TEST where ID in (1001,1002);
```

Also please advise whether the delete operation will be faster with or without using the primary key.

Comment: The link mentioned above is for multiple select statement. But i am looking for delete operation.

Comment: It's the same question though, really.  You basically have to use a table or a CTE to store the ids, that's the only option.

Comment: Are the number sequence then u can create table then select from it as much as u want

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42487575) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9084247) from the duplicate can be applied to DELETE as well

Answer (score 2):

The simplest option (from my point of view) is to store that *huge* list into a table, and then

```
delete from test
  where id in (select id from a_table_that_contains_huge_list_of_entries)
```

Will it be faster with a *primary key* involved? I suppose that it is not a *primary key* that matters, but whether something is indexed or not (doesn't have to be a primary key). But, will Oracle really use that index? Who knows; depends on the optimizer. It may choose that full table scan is more appropriate. Check the explain plan.

Answer (score 1):

If the data are sequence u can do the below

```
Create table seqnumbrs as
select level as id from dual connect by level <= 10000;

Delete from tab1 were id in (select id from seqnumbrs);
```

You can create pk or index on the table for performane