# More than 1000 parameters in an SQL IN (VBA)

Tags: sql, vba, oracle

I'm making an oracle query from vba and ran into the limitation that there can't be more than 1000 entries in a SQL IN statement.

```
   LRow_Last_Product = Workbooks("test.xlsm").Worksheets("Check").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For Each RngZelle In Workbooks("test.xlsm").Worksheets("Check").Range("A7:A" & LRow_Last_Product)
    
        If StrISINs = "" Then
            StrISINs = "'" & RngZelle.Value & "'"
        Else
            StrISINs = StrISINs & ", '" & RngZelle.Value & "'"
        End If
    Next RngZelle

'WHERE
StrSQL = StrSQL & "t.externref IN (" & StrISINs & ")"
```

I was thinking about creating a function that would generate a second IN with an OR if there are more than 1000 parameters. What is the most efficient way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: As this is not a VBA but an SQL problem, you should tag this question with SQL and the DBS you are working on (I assume it's Oracle because of the 1000). That said: There are many questions and discussions about how to deal with this limitation, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722220/sql-in-clause-1000-item-limit

Comment: I know how to solve it in SQL,  I'm interested in the VBA code to do it.

Comment: But in VBA you just to some string tinkering so that you end up with a valid SQL statement. So write down the SQL statement you want to reach and the rest should be trivial. If you have difficulties with that, show us the final SQL you want to reach

Comment: I'd like to end up with something like this: StrSQL = StrSQL & "t.externref IN (" & first1000Isins & ") OR t.externref IN (" & second1000Isins & ")" OR ....

Comment: "I was thinking about creating a function that would generate a second IN with an OR if there are more than 1000 parameters" sounds like a reasonable plan.  I've done this in the past and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already wrote, it's just a little bit string handling to create the (multiple) IN-Clauses. There are thousands of different ways to do this.
**Just for fun** I came up with the following function.

It first calculates the number of In-Clauses needed and create an array of strings of that size.

Now it writes the data of your range in chunks of n (`maxPerClause`) into a (one-dimensional) array and uses the `Join`-function to combine that with a comma-separator (and optional the single quotes if you deal with strings)

Finally it uses the `Join`-function to join everything together.

```
Function CreateInClause(r As Range, fieldName As String, Optional asString As Boolean = True) As String
    Const maxPerClause = 10
    Dim clausesNeeded As Long
    clausesNeeded = ((r.Count - 1) \ maxPerClause) + 1
    
    Dim data As Variant
    data = r.Value2
    
    ReDim clauses(1 To clausesNeeded) As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To clausesNeeded
        
        ' Calculate Start and number of elements for the next IN-Clause
        Dim startRow As Long, rowCount As Long
        startRow = (i - 1) * maxPerClause + 1
        If startRow + maxPerClause > r.Count Then
            rowCount = r.Count - startRow + 1
        Else
            rowCount = maxPerClause
        End If
        
        ' Copy the elemens of the next IN-Clause to 1-dimensional array
        ReDim elements(1 To rowCount)
        Dim j As Long
        For j = 1 To rowCount
            elements(j) = data(startRow + j - 1, 1)
        Next
        
        ' Create everything that will go inside the (...) of one IN-Clause
        If asString Then
            clauses(i) = "'" & Join(elements, "','") & "'"
        Else
            clauses(i) = Join(elements, ",")
        End If
    Next
    
    ' Now join the created IN-Clauses to one statement
    CreateInClause = fieldName & " IN (" & Join(clauses, ") OR " & fieldName & " IN (") & ")"
End Function
```

Just for test reasons I set the number of elements for every IN-Clause to 10 - once you are sure everything works you can set it to 1000.

**Explanation:**

Consider you have a Range with 26 cells, holding the values from 'A' to 'Z'.

Number of IN clauses = 3 `((26 - 1) \ 10) + 1)` (The `\` is the integer division operator).

The first iteration will write the values `A` to `J` into array `elements`.  `Join` will combine them to the string `'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'` and writes it into `clauses(1)`. Same goes for 2nd and 3rd iteration, only that for the last iteration there are only 6 elements left.

When this is done, you have 3 elements in `clauses`:

```
'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'
'J','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T'
'U','V','W','X','Y','Z'
```

Now you join those together to create the final IN-Clauses. As the fieldname is needed within the clause, you need to pass it as parameter. You end up with

```
t.externref IN ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J') OR t.externref IN ('K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T') OR t.externref IN ('U','V','W','X','Y','Z')
```

---

In your code, you can remove the for-loop and instead write

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Workbooks("test.xlsm").Worksheets("Check").Range("A7:A" & LRow_Last_Product)
StrSQL = StrSQL & CreateInClause(r, "t.externref", true)
```

Comment: I've tried with 617 values in the range and it generated this: t.externref IN ('value1','value2','value3','value4','value5','value6','value7','value8','value9

Comment: FYI I've set maxPerClause to 100

Comment: Looks like just a limitation of the debugger. Answer accepted Sir!

Comment: Maybe not a bad idea to wrap the whole return value in an extra set of parentheses, in case the return value is used in queries with other clauses ?  Would not harm even where that's not the case....

Comment: If the value has a single quote in it then you will either get an invalid statement or be subject to an SQL injection attack. You would be better to generate a static parameterised query and then sending the values with the SQL statement as bind variables.